# How to edit tables in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny

```
library(quantmod)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    textInput("Stock","Input Stock"),
    textInput("Date","Input Start Date"),
    textInput("Dateto","Input End Date"),
    actionButton("GO","GO"),
    tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

    data <- eventReactive(input$GO,{
        req(input$Stock)
        getSymbols(input$Stock,src = "yahoo", from=input$Date,to=input$Dateto,auto.assign=F)

    })


    output$table <- renderTable({
        data()
    })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

here is my code for my current r shiny document, it is outputting a data table of the input stock as requested, however how would I go about editing the table 'data' before outputting it , for example adding a column with moving averages inside it

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to keep your `data` object as an `xts` `zoo`, one option is to store the results of your call to `getSymbols`, convert to a `data.frame`, and then assign a new column. In the example below, I arbitrarily select values for your inputs (tracking AAPL stock over last 90 days), and calculate the rolling 7-day average closing price using the `rollmeanr()` function from `zoo`:

```
raw_data <- getSymbols("AAPL",src = "yahoo", from=Sys.Date()-90,to=Sys.Date(),auto.assign=F)
df <- as.data.frame(raw_data)
# k is the window size for rolling mean
# fill = NA tells the function to fill missing values with NA
df$moving_7_day <- rollmeanr(df$AAPL.Close, k = 7, fill = NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your `eventReactive` function, you can modify the object and add or remove columns, etc.. You could keep it in `xts` format or convert it to a data.table, for example. 
Below is an example adding a 7-day rolling mean of closing price to the `xts` object:

```
invisible(lapply(c("quantmod", "shiny"), require, character.only=TRUE))  

ui <- fluidPage(
    textInput("Stock","Input Stock"),
    dateRangeInput("Date", "Input Date Range"),
    actionButton("GO","GO"),
    tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

    data <- eventReactive(input$GO,{
        req(input$Stock)
        dt <- getSymbols(input$Stock, src="yahoo", 
                from=input$Date[1], to=input$Date[2],
                auto.assign=FALSE)
        cn <- paste(input$Stock, "7d_Avg", sep=".")
        dt$roll <- rollapply(dt[,4], 7, mean)
        colnames(dt)[colnames(dt) == "roll"] <- cn
        return(dt)
    })

    output$table <- renderTable({
        data()
    })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```